# Call function for each item in iterable

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I'm wondering if there is a more "succinct" or pythonic way of doing this.

```
foo = range(10)
def bar (num):
    if num > 5:
        print "Num >5"
map(bar, food)
```

This is a rough representation of what I'm doing, except the `foo` is a list of object id's and `bar` is really `bar.delay` because it's a Celery task.

Now this *works*, but it has the side effect of generating a list of the results (which is all `None`). Is there any other way to do this other than a for loop?

Comment: for loop is the most Pythonic, but if you are really bored of that method, see my xmap function in the question I asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994471/why-is-my-xmap-function-not-any-faster-than-built-in-map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with a loop?:

```
for item in foo:
    bar(item)
```

Of course, if you want to get fancy, you could make a generator `gen = (bar(item) for item in foo)` or use `itertools.imap` and then use the [`consume`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe from itertools...

Comment: Because I don't like having those two lines scattered through my code. Feels bad when I'm used to things like generators and list comprehensions. But, given Shashank's performance results I'll go with the for loop.

Comment: Comprehensions and `map`-like functions are all intended to build some object (a list or a generator, etc. etc.).  If you just want to iterate through an object and do something but not build anything, then a for-loop is always the cleanest solution.